# Does this basis generate the discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology

In Topology by Munkres, Lemma 13.2, on page 78, the following is written:

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose that $\tilde{C}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $\tilde{C}$ such that $x\in C \subset U$. Then $\tilde{C}$ is a basis for $\textbf{the}$ topology of $X$.

In the next to next paragraph, the following text is written:

Let $\tau$ be the collection of open sets of $X$; we must show that the topology $\tau'$ generated by $\tilde{C}$ equals the topology $\tau$.

Here too, I am confused as to what is meant by, "Let $\tau$ be the collection of open sets of $X$". Is it the set of all open subsets of $X$? This is the cental point of my confusion. $\tau$ is being compared with $\tau'$. According to the text, "$\tau$ is the collection of open sets of $X$". Is $\tau$ the discrete topology? If not, what is the nature of $\tau$?

I have attached a screenshot of this page of the book below:
[image]

Comment: > What does he mean by the topology of  X?

Generally, a topological space $X$ is actually the pair $(X, \tau)$ where $\tau$ is the collections of open sets of $X$, denoted as *the* topology of $X$. The Lemma in Munkres is stated in general terms for any topology that a space $X$ has, but in most contexts there is a standard topology for a typical space. For $\mathbb{R}$, it is typically open intervals, for $\mathbb{N}$, it is typically the discrete topology

Comment: @smailliwniloc Ok. But in the second statement (within the proof), he talks about a specific topology. He writes, "Let  be the collection of open sets of ; we must show that the topology ′ generated by ̃ equals the topology ." So  is the collection of open sets of . Is this the collection of all possible open subsets of ? In other words, I am confused about the nature of  which being compared with ′ (the topology generated by ̃).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a famously confusing part of Munkres; there many questions on the site about it.

He first introduces the notion of a basis $\mathcal{B}$ on a **set** $X$ (no topology yet): it obeys the two conditions

1. For all $x \in X$ there is some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B$.
2. For all $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ there is some $B_3 \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

In that case we have that the topology $\mathcal{T}$ *generated by* $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of all subsets of $X$ that can be written exactly as unions of sets from $\mathcal{B}$. We then call $\mathcal{B}$ a basis for the space (!) $(X, \mathcal{T})$. So the latter really means that all open sets $X$ (i.e. sets from $\mathcal{T}$) are *unions* from $\mathcal{B}$.

In this paragraph he starts with a space that already has a topology (not named at first (later called simply $\mathcal{T}$), but that's what "space" implies), so really $(X,\mathcal{T})$.
He then *assumes* we have a family $\mathcal{C}$ (of **open** sets, so he assumes $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{T}$ really) such that

$$\forall U \in \mathcal{T}: \forall x \in U: \exists C \in \mathcal{C}: x \in C \subseteq U\tag{1}$$

and then he wants to show

- $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis in the above sense on $X$.
- The topology on $X$ generated by $\mathcal{C}$ (using unions, remember) is exactly the $\mathcal{T}$ that we started with.

Read this paragraph with that in mind (and the fact that he has these goals) and all will be clear, I think. It comes down to the fact that $(1)$ is just a handy/fancy way of stating that all $U$ in the topology are unions from $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: When I teach this part of Munkres, I like to bring in a new terminology, to kind of break up this confusion: I call that first thing he introduces a *topological basis* on the set $S$. It's important on its own, because so many topologies are constructed by first constructing a certain topological basis, and then taking the topology that is generated by that topological basis.

Comment: @LeeMosher in my own education we were taught about generating families (called subbases) first because they’re even more fundamental, and used in initial topologies (which came soon after). Any family of subsets obeying $(1)$ was a network (the Arhangelskij notion). Bases were relatively unimportant.